# Data structures - Abstract data type (ADT) VS Concrete data type (CDT)

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, abstract-data-type

So while studying data structures I came up with a question.

A CDT is a fully fledged ADT i.e. an implementation of the ADT.

therefore the .h file is actually an ADT (only operations and no discussion about how they will be performed).

But by showing the .cpp file alongside i.e. the implementation file.

Can we conclude that we made a Concrete data type of stack using a concrete data structure i.e. an array or a linked list?

Is that the case? correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays, lists and trees are concrete datatypes. They are basic data structures typically provided by the computer language.
Stacks, queues and heaps are abstract datatypes. They are just ideas, i.e. "black boxes" with a defined behavior. To implement them, you have to choose a suitable concrete datatype.
In particular, stacks and queues can be implemented by arrays or linked lists.
A heap can be implemented by an array or a binary tree

Answer (score 1):

Um, not quite, at least in the conventional use of the terms.

An *abstract data type* is a [mathematical model of a type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) based on a statement of the state and operations available.

I think you might be thinking of an abstract *class*, which is a class that's not fully implemented and so must be refined to make a concrete class.

The `.h` files specify the *interface* provided by a class. But, given inlining and such, it doesnt' fit into the abstract/concrete distinction very well: you can have a `.h` file that fully implements a concrete class.